# Dynamically replace the grid name

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code like

```
"where" :   window.parent.grdRMAReport.CurrentFilter,
```

grdRMAReport has to be dynamic i.e. it can be grdrefundreport also. I want it to be a variable.

i tried like

```
window.parent.+varname+.CurrentFilter,
```

and

`'window.parent.'+varname+'.CurrentFilter',`

both does not work. 1st throws error and second becomes a string. How do i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
window.parent[varname]['CurrentFilter']
```

Comment: @ Man Programmer - what about dots ?

Comment: in object dot represent to it member but it not working dynamically for that case change into array